# Error when retrieving child properties in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, hql

Im getting this error, im trying to access a child property using one-to-many relation in hibernate:

> org.hibernate.QueryException: illegal attempt to dereference collection [sigtccontr0_.ID_OBJETIVO.children] with element property reference [idIniciativa] [from org.citi.tablero.contraloria.planes.model.db.hibernate.dto.SigTcContraloriaObjetivos p where p.children.idIniciativa = 1]

This is my query:

```
String sql = "from SigTcContraloriaObjetivos p where p.children.idIniciativa = 1";
```

Dto ´s:

```
public class SigTcContraloriaObjetivos {

    private Long idObjetivo;
    private String descripcion;
    private Set<SigTcContraloriaIniciativas> children;

public class SigTcContraloriaIniciativas {

    private Long idIniciativa;
    private String descripcion;
    private Long idObjetivo;
```

Mappings:

```xml
<class dynamic-insert="false" dynamic-update="true" mutable="true"
           name="org.citi.tablero.contraloria.planes.model.db.hibernate.dto.SigTcContraloriaObjetivos"
           optimistic-lock="version" polymorphism="implicit" select-before-update="false"
           table="SIG_TC_CONTRALORIA_OBJETIVOS">
    <id column="ID_OBJETIVO" name="idObjetivo">
        <generator class="sequence">
            <param name="sequence">SEQ_SIG_CONTRALORIA_OBJETIVOS</param>
        </generator>    
    </id>
    <property column="DESCRIPCION" name="descripcion"/>
     <set name="children" inverse="false" cascade="all" lazy="false">
        <key column="ID_OBJETIVO"/>
        <one-to-many class="SigTcContraloriaIniciativas"/>
    </set>          
</class>

<class dynamic-insert="false" dynamic-update="true" mutable="true" name="org.citi.tablero.contraloria.planes.model.db.hibernate.dto.SigTcContraloriaIniciativas"
        optimistic-lock="version" polymorphism="implicit" select-before-update="false" table="SIG_TC_CONTRALORIA_INICIATIVAS">
    <id column="ID_INICIATIVA" name="idIniciativa">
        <generator class="sequence">
            <param name="sequence">SEQ_SIG_CONTRALORIA_INICIATIVA</param>
        </generator>    
    </id>
    <property column="DESCRIPCION" name="descripcion"/>
    <property column="ID_OBJETIVO" name="idObjetivo" /> 

</class>
```

Any idea how to access to `idIniciativa`?

Update: when using the query provided: **"select p from SigTcContraloriaObjetivos p join p.children c where c.idIniciativa = 1"**

query.list() returns:

Object1:

1. SigTcContraloriaObjetivos
   1.1 SigTcContraloriaIniciativas   (child)
2. SigTcContraloriaIniciativas

Object2:

1. SigTcContraloriaObjetivos
   1.1 SigTcContraloriaIniciativas   (child)
2. SigTcContraloriaIniciativas

And i need:

1. Object 1: SigTcContraloriaObjetivos -> SigTcContraloriaIniciativas
   (Child)
2. Object 2: SigTcContraloriaObjetivos -> SigTcContraloriaIniciativas
   (Child)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access a collection that way with Hibernate. Something like the following should work:

```
select p from SigTcContraloriaObjetivos p join p.children c where c.idIniciativa = 1
```

See here for more info: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins

Note, this is for Hibernate 3.3.

Comment: Hi, i also tried that but in that way, the problem is the following:

The query returns me:

Object1:
-SigTcContraloriaObjetivos
--------------------------SigTcContraloriaIniciativas
-SigTcContraloriaIniciativas


Object2:
-SigTcContraloriaObjetivos
--------------------------SigTcContraloriaIniciativas
-SigTcContraloriaIniciativas



and i need:
Object 1: SigTcContraloriaObjetivos -> SigTcContraloriaIniciativas
Object 2: SigTcContraloriaObjetivos -> SigTcContraloriaIniciativas

Comment: It looks really bad here, so i updated the post, thanks for your replie

Comment: @Victor Elizondo Are you getting more results from the query than you expect? I'm a little confused by your edit.

Comment: Look, if I use this query: "from SigTcContraloriaObjetivos" It gives me the correct result, but when i add the join it returns me more objects inside the array, containning one objects of Objetivos and one of Iniciativas.

I want to add a condition to the child, thats what im trying

Comment: I'm still confused. Are you expecting the SigTcContraloriaObjetivos objects returned to only contain the matching  SigTcContraloriaIniciativas object in their associated children set? If so, the query will not do that for you.

Comment: I only want a list of Objetivos with their respective childs, i dont want a list of objects containning Objetivos and Iniciativas

Comment: Yes, im looking for that then how can i do it? Because this simple query: "from SigTcContraloriaObjetivos" does that. But i want to implement where conditions for the childs contained in the Set.

Comment: OK, somehow is working now but now i want to add another child level. Should this works in the same way?

Comment: @Victor Elizondo What do you mean when you say 'another child level'?

Comment: Hi, the query is working now but it´s not as I expected, By adding a new child I mean adding a new Set of a new class in SigTcIniciativas with the corresponding mapping file. 
Also I just found out that when you have two SigTcContraloriaIniciativas related to one SigTcContraloriaObjetivos the query returns duplicate SigTcContraloriaObjetivos, how can i solve this?

Comment: please look at this new post i created: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16967482/hibernate-one-to-many-query-using-mappings , i marked your answer as accepted because it helped me but i still having some problems