# hibernate one to many query using mappings

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, hql

I have 3 classes with the corresponding relationship parent child on them:

//SigTcContraloriaObjetivos, SigTcContraloriaIniciativas, SigTcContraloriaAcciones

```
<class dynamic-insert="false" dynamic-update="true" mutable="true" name="org.citi.tablero.contraloria.planes.model.db.hibernate.dto.SigTcContraloriaObjetivos" optimistic-lock="version" polymorphism="implicit" select-before-update="false" table="SIG_TC_CONTRALORIA_OBJETIVOS">
    <id column="ID_OBJETIVO" name="idObjetivo">
        <generator class="sequence">
            <param name="sequence">SEQ_SIG_CONTRALORIA_OBJETIVOS</param>
        </generator>    
    </id>
    <property column="DESCRIPCION" name="descripcion"/>
     <set name="children" inverse="false" cascade="all" lazy="false">
        <key column="ID_OBJETIVO"/>
        <one-to-many class="SigTcContraloriaIniciativas"/>
    </set>          
</class>

<class dynamic-insert="false" dynamic-update="true" mutable="true" name="org.citi.tablero.contraloria.planes.model.db.hibernate.dto.SigTcContraloriaIniciativas" optimistic-lock="version" polymorphism="implicit" select-before-update="false" table="SIG_TC_CONTRALORIA_INICIATIVAS">
    <id column="ID_INICIATIVA" name="idIniciativa">
        <generator class="sequence">
            <param name="sequence">SEQ_SIG_CONTRALORIA_INICIATIVA</param>
        </generator>    
    </id>
    <property column="DESCRIPCION" name="descripcion"/>
    <property column="ID_OBJETIVO" name="idObjetivo" /> 
     <set  name="children" inverse="false" cascade="all" lazy="false">
        <key column="ID_INICIATIVA"/>
        <one-to-many class="SigTcContraloriaAcciones"/>
    </set>      
</class>

<class dynamic-insert="false" dynamic-update="true" mutable="true" name="org.citi.tablero.contraloria.planes.model.db.hibernate.dto.SigTcContraloriaAcciones" optimistic-lock="version" polymorphism="implicit" select-before-update="false" table="SIG_TC_CONTRALORIA_ACCIONES">
    <id column="ID_ACCION" name="idAccion">
        <generator class="sequence">
            <param name="sequence">SEQ_SIG_CONTRALORIA_ACCIONES</param>
        </generator>    
    </id>
    <property column="DESCRIPCION" name="descripcion"/>
    <property column="ID_INICIATIVA" name="idIniciativa" /> 
    <property column="ID_ORGANIZACION" name="idOrganizacion" />
</class>
```

I need a way to select one SigTcContraloriaIniciativa with the associated SigTcContraloriaObjetivo and with the associated SigTcContraloriaAccion

This is the query im using:

```
String sql = "select distinct p from SigTcContraloriaObjetivos p join p.children c join c.children b where and b.idOrganizacion = 8";
```

(In the database i only have one SigTcContraloriaAccion with idOrganizacion= 8, so my expected result is one SigTcContraloriaObjetivos with the corresponding SigTcContraloriaIniciativas with the corresponding SigTcContraloriaAccion im selecting)

My problem is when I execute query.list() it returns me one SigTcContraloriaObjetivos (as expected), two SigTcContraloriaIniciativas(Not expected, i only expect one), and two SigTcContraloriasAcciones (only one expected) for each SigTcContraloriaIniciativas

UPDATE:

This is the image of the tables:

[image: TABLES]

Comment: Can you show us clearly the data in the database?

Comment: Sure, i will update the post shortly

Comment: in the database there should be a join table for SigTcContraloriasAcciones and SigTcContraloriaIniciativas. What is in this table?

Comment: The column ID_INICIATIVA is the relation between those tables...http://i.stack.imgur.com/KJlks.jpg

Comment: the relation between objetivo and iniciativas is "ID_OBJETIVO", the realtion between iniciativas and acciones is "ID_INICIATIVA", therefore one OBJETIVO has many INICIATIVAS, and one INICIATIVA has many ACCIONES

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your query is returning the correct result but that you do not understand it.

As you have stated, the correct SigTcContraloriaObjetivos object is being returned. What you get back is the object and ALL its associations (assuming fetch type is EAGER). Those associations are NOT filtered based upon your query though.

I think you are expecting:

```
SigTcContraloriaObjetivos (ID=1)
----- SigTcContraloriaIniciativas (ID=1)
       ----- SigTcContraloriaAcciones (ID=5)
```

JPA/Hibernate does not work that way. The result of such a query will always be the object(s) that meet the criteria and those object(s) will contain all their associated objects.

Comment: Yes that´s the expected result i want! Well, then how can i achieve this result if you say hibernate doesnt work in that way?

Comment: I have to ask why you want that result given that your query is searching for SigTcContraloriaObjetivos and you have got back the correct result.

Comment: Because i want to set where conditions to SigTcContraloriaAcciones 
For example, if i want to query all the SigTcContraloriaAcciones where idOrganizazion = 8. The result that i need is the SigTcContraloriaAcciones with idOrganizacion = 8, the SigTcContraloriaIniciativas related to this SigTcContraloriaAcciones , and the SigTcContraloriaObjetivos related to this SigTcContraloriaIniciativas

Comment: Maybe i should use inverse way but i dont know does this works or if it applies here.

Comment: Let me express it in SQL syntax what im looking for:  select * from sig_tc_contraloria_objetivos o inner join       sig_tc_contraloria_iniciativas i on o.id_objetivo = i.id_objetivo   inner join sig_tc_contraloria_acciones a on i.id_iniciativa =   a.id_iniciativa where a.id_organizacion = 8;

Comment: You could use the inverse but you would need to set up ManyToOne mappings from SigTcContraloriaAcciones to SigTcContraloriaIniciativas and from SigTcContraloriaIniciativas to SigTcContraloriaObjetivos.

Comment: should i eliminate my one-to-many relations in order to do this?

Comment: No, you shouldn't need to do that. Just add the ManyToOne mappings.

Comment: you can add columns in select query to get only those columns of child table with where condition and hibernate will return object[]. You can then convert Object[] into your DTO class by iterating a array. Like String sql = "select distinct p, c.description, b.description from SigTcContraloriaObjetivos p join p.children c join c.children b where and b.idOrganizacion = 8";

Comment: @JamesB Well, i keep getting an error i couldnt fix, related that SigTcAcciones couldnt find a setter of a property, but thanks anyway